# Angular2 and xampp server

Tags: php, mysql, angular, xampp

I want build web application using angular2 with MySql database on xampp server and php by server side. Is it posible? How start do this and connect to server? Thanks for answers and advices!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite similar to how I develop with Angular 1 and PHP on a LAMP installation. It is possible of course. Angular 2 (when transpiled) is your client side code. With Angular you can call PHP-services. For example, I created PHP services that encode/decode JSON and read/write from DB's. So the PHP is server side and talks to the DB, Angular is client side and talks to the PHP services via REST.

This url explaines using databases with PHP very well: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17

An addition: Making Rest-API's of your PHP modules also requires you to secure them. If you have an API that updates your DB, then anyone can call it and ruin your application. Since Rest-API's are http calls you can use basic authentication with SSL to secure them.

Comment: So if angular2 has module structure, should I create .php file in every page view? And how connect it with .ts file?

Comment: You only need to create .php files for your services. For example, when you create a .php file to read a record from a DB you start with decoding the JSON-input of your service in php variables and set up a database connection, read your record, , encode the result back to JSON and return the result (or an error if something goes wrong).

Comment: Within your Angular-code (which is in your .ts files) you can use the http service to call these .php files and get your result in JSON format and use that result to render your page. This is described here: https://angular.io/guide/http.